# Using instanceof with Java Enums

Tags: java, generics, enums, instanceof

I have a situation where I'm receiving an `enum` from an external system, and for which I need to return an `enum` of our own. The two enums have the exact same literal values in them:

```
// externalEnum is guaranteed not to be null 
public static MyEnum enumToEnum(final Enum<? extends Enum<?>> externalEnum)
{
    if( externalEnum instanceof MyEnum )
    {
        return (MyEnum)enumType;
    }
    else
    {
        return MyEnum.valueOf(externalEnum.name());
    }
}
```

However, the compiler squeals the following:

```
    [javac] found   : java.lang.Enum<capture#117 of ? extends java.lang.Enum<?>>
    [javac] required: myEnum
    [javac]             if( externalEnum instanceof MyEnum )
```

I got a version of that function that works by simply returning `MyEnum.valueOf(externalEnum.name())` - it works and that's all that matters. However, I'm baffled about the compiler error.

I'm trying to understand the reification process of generics in this case. An instance of `Enum<? extends Enum<?>>` or simply `Enum<?>` can be a `MyEnum` (given that the later can never be anything other than a subtype of the former.)

So the `instanceof` test should work, but there seems to be something in the generic definition of `Enum` (and perhaps the fact that Enums cannot be extended) that causes the compiler to puke with that particular statement.

The workaround for me is easy, but I like to understand the problems well, and any insight on this will be appreciated.

- Luis.

Comment: Your error message contains a lowercase "myEnum", but I don't see a lowercase "myEnum" anywhere in your code. Where is lowercase "myEnum" defined in your code? What's it doing in this function?

Comment: Also, is `return (MyEnum)enumType;` intentional, or should it perhaps be `return (MyEnum)externalEnum`? When I change it your first example works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why even bother if both are the same?

```
public static MyEnum enumToEnum(final Enum<? extends Enum<?>> externalEnum)
{
    try
    {
        return MyEnum.valueOf(externalEnum.name());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return MyEnum.UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Comment: Duh! Good point. It's amazing I didn't realize this until after 7 months :)

Answer (score 3):

My (possibly flawed) analysis of your problem is that the two wildcards in your type definition are separate from each other:

```
Enum<? extends Enum<?>>
```

means "An Enum of a type that extends Enum that extends some unknown type".

What you want is probably more like this:

```
Enum<T extends Enum<T>>
```

which means "An Enum of a type that extends Enum of itself". That is a curious recursive definition (which somehow loops back to `Comparable<T>`), but it's just how `Enum`s are defined.

Of course your static method would need to take a type parameter `<T>` for this to work. Try this:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> MyEnum enumToEnum(final T externalEnum) {
    if (externalEnum instanceof MyEnum) {
        return (MyEnum) externalEnum;
    } else {
        return MyEnum.valueOf(externalEnum.name());
    }
}
```

Edit: fixing the compiler error caused by a wrong identifier makes the code in the question compile for me. So my analysis is definitely flawed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `externalEnum` rather than `enumType` in your first return statement.

That fixed, it compiles in Eclipse and with ant.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a situation where I'm receiving an enum from an external system, and for which I need to return an enum of our own.

The instanceof will return false if both classes are loaded by different classloader and/or do have a different minor/major version. Take this into account as well.